# React native project crashing with Redux Toolkit

Tags: react-native, react-redux, expo, redux-toolkit

I'm using an Expo Bare Workflow setup with my React Native App.

I followed this guide EXACTLY https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/quick-start copy pasted everything.

Imported

```
import { store } from "./src/main/redux/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
```

on my `App.js` but it crashes when I build the app for Expo Go testing using `eas update`. *If I remove those two imports, the app works fine.*

I've followed the quickstart guide exactly, so for the code you can refer to the quick start guide as it might be redundant if I still post it here.

There's no error message from the App because it crashes on startup. I do get one from xcode saying `com.facebook.ABI46_0_0React.ExceptionsManagerQueue` and the rest are some obscure messages

Comment: can you add the error message please?

Comment: Did you try running the app in debug?

Comment: Please share your code and entire stack trace, even if you think it is obscure. Even if your code is directly copied from tutorial, it is clearly working in the sandbox and not for you. Don't worry about redundancy. There is hardly any useful code in your question to debug.

If you say the import is causing the crash then clearly the issue is in the imported file which you need to share if you need help debugging.

Comment: Also have you followed the update process described [here](https://docs.expo.dev/eas-update/runtime-versions/#avoiding-crashes-with-incompatible-updates)?

Comment: I'm guessing the issue you are facing is... (It's just an assumption)... you might have installed redux and redux toolkit and then tried to update the app using eas update without creating and installing the new build. If not, then as @sushrut619 pointed out, you need to share the code as well.

Comment: Anyone find an aswer to this?  I'm having the same issue of my expo app crashing on eas update when using the redux toolkit.

Comment: @Collin I ended up using TestFlight. App works there.

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74283724/expo-crashes-with-redux-toolkit#comment131528603_74283724

Comment: https://forums.expo.dev/t/expo-go-with-react-redux-crashes-on-published-app-but-works-in-local/67949