# Expo crashes with redux toolkit

Tags: react-native, react-redux, expo

I just added react-redux with reduxjs/toolkit on react-native.

I tried in dev mode and its been working fine.
I tried with expo start --no-dev --minify and it crashed.
I decided to publish it and when I launched it, my app instantly crashed.

Why ?

package.json

```
{
  "name": "cusual test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.6",
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "eas-cli": "^2.5.1",
    "expo": "~46.0.16",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.14.6",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.6",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.14",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.69.1",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.12",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

This line makes my app crahes :

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router />
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

If I comment provider's lines, it doesn't crash anymore.

Did I miss anything ?

I'm using SDK 46 and expo 6.0.6.
Thanks for help.

Comment: I’m having the same issue.  Have you found a solution?

Comment: Yes, it was because of babel.config.js, I remove some unused things and the app sto pcrashing, i don't even udnerstand the link between them but my crashed was solved

Comment: Can you be more.specific. Perhaps you can put it in the answer.

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73788057/react-native-project-crashing-with-redux-toolkit

Comment: I have a similar situation but I posted in the expo forums it may make more sense there https://forums.expo.dev/t/expo-go-with-react-redux-crashes-on-published-app-but-works-in-local/67949

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue. Looks to be caused by a bug in the Redux code. Have a look at this issue on GitHub:

https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/4443

Describes a crash that happens when code is minified and running in production mode.